Modelling blender limit location extention/retraction in Three.js and cannon-es
I am trying to load a .glb file created in blender to a three.js with cannon-es for physics/gravity.
My goal is to be able to extend and retract each individual actuator added to my model. The model is a tabletop with 4x actuators in each corner and when an actuator is extended I want it (using the gravity)adjust the tilt/pitch of the table top attached (as it would in real life).
I have created the model in blender and have the foollowing heirarchy of objects;
TableTop 
-> 4x Actuator Bases (naming is Actuator1_Base etc) 
-> 4x Actuator Rods (naming is Actuator1_Rod etc)

I have applied a limit location constraint to each of the actuators in blender so it can only slide the set length.
Then in my app I load the model and traverse over it saving the details into an TableTop instance.Do I neeed to then stick each part of the table together and add physics?
or am I over complicating this, is it possible to just use the limit constraint from the glb at all to slide each part out/in (up/down).
If not, can you point me in the right direction of how I move each element to 'push' the table top?
